# Hibernate Creación de Tablas

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mariadb

Buenas a todos,hace poco comencé a trabajar con la herramienta ORM **Hibernate**,tratando de entender el funcionamiento de esta tecnología eh creado un simple **POJO** llamado Deportistas el cual pretendo mapear a la base de datos,a través de las anotaciones que me ofrece **Hibernate**,pues bien tambien dispongo de otra clase **HibernateUtil** que me devuelve un **Session** **Factory** para poder persistir los objetos en la Base de datos Relacional,es esta precisa clase la que me esta dando el error por algún motivo que ahora mismo no veo les adjunto el mensaje de error a si como todas las clases que estoy utilizando.

---

### Clase Deportistas

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "deportistas")
  public class Deportistas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "codDeportista")
    private int codDeportista;

    @Column(name = "nombreDeportista", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(60)")
    private String nombreDeportista;

    @Column(name = "dniDeportista", columnDefinition = "CHAR(12)")
    private String dniDeportista;

    @Column(name = "pais", columnDefinition = "CHAR(4)")
    private String pais;

    public int getCodDeportista() {
        return codDeportista;
    }

    public void setCodDeportista(int codDeportista) {
        this.codDeportista = codDeportista;
    }

    public String getNombreDeportista() {
        return nombreDeportista;
    }

    public void setNombreDeportista(String nombreDeportista) {
        this.nombreDeportista = nombreDeportista;
    }

    public String getDniDeportista() {
        return dniDeportista;
    }

    public void setDniDeportista(String dniDeportista) {
        this.dniDeportista = dniDeportista;
    }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

}
```

---

### Clase HibernateUtil

*Aquí es donde el IDE me esta diciendo que esta el error en la linea 20*

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        try {           
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

---

### Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Configuración de conexión a la base de datos -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateolimpiadas</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!-- Pool de conexiones JDBC (se usa la que viene por defecto) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Dialecto SQL -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Muestra en la consola todas las consultas SQL ejecutadas -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Elimina y vuelve a crear el esquema de la base de datos al iniciar 
            si siempre esta sin comentar cada vez que lo ejecuto crea las tablas para 
            ello poner create-drop, si no quiero que vuelva a crear las tablas pondré 
            update -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mapea las siguientes clases anotadas si trabajásemos con mapeo XML 
            en lugar de class pondríamos resource -->
        <mapping class="proyecto.Deportistas" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

### Estructura de el proyecto

*Añadida al ClassPath todas las librerías requeridas de Hibernate*
[image: Estructura de Proyecto]

---

### Carga y persistencia en un main

```
public class DataLoader {

    private static HibernateUtil hibernate ;
    private static Session sesion ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hibernate = new HibernateUtil();
        sesion = hibernate.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        sesion.beginTransaction();

        Deportistas d1 = new Deportistas();
        d1.setNombreDeportista("n1");
        d1.setDniDeportista("33.698.123-H");
        d1.setPais("HJKl");

        sesion.save(d1);

        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

---

### Traza de el error

```
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at main.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at main.HibernateUtil.<init>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at main.DataLoader.main(DataLoader.java:16)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2441)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more
```

---

Como se puede observar esta dando un error en mi clase **HibernateUtil** la cual no se si es la forma correcta de crearla pues me eh basado en algún ejemplo que eh visto por la red,como dato adicional decir que la base de datos la eh creado previamente en **MYSQL**.

De ante mano agradecer toda la ayuda que pueda aportar la comunidad a si como cualquier consejo  para alguien que esta empezando con **Hibernate**. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu `Hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<!-- Dialecto SQL -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

...estás usando un dialecto diseñado para versiones antiguas de `MySQL` que no funciona con versiones más recientes, o como es tu caso, con MariaDB.

Esto explica el error que recibes:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1

Siguiendo, las sugerencias en esta [otra página](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43720565/4955425), intenta cambiar tu dialecto por una de las que corresponde a MariaDB:

- `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect`

Y si no funcionan, puedes intentar las que corresponden a MySQL, pero para versiones más recientes:

- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect`
- `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect`

Comment: Muchas gracias esto resolvió mi problema utilizando simplemente la Versión org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect funciono perfectamente,deduzco que cada vez que actualicen la vercion de MYSQL habrá que utilizar su dialect correspondiente a la vercion que se este ejecutando en la maquina,gracias por la ayuda.